# How do you add a line break in yattag?

Tags: html, python-3.x, yattag

When generating an HTML document in [`yattag`](http://www.yattag.org/), how do you add a line break (`<br/>`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `doc.stag('br')` since the `stag` method produces a self closing tag. You'll get `<br />`

Answer (score 1):

For HTML: `doc.stag('br')`

For XML you can use this built-in method: `doc.nl()`

This works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

use doc.asis('
') they mention it in their web site for doc type hopefully this will help you in the new line.

Comment: There is a build in method for that, `doc.nl()`, this however adds a plain newline in the generated text, not a `<br/>` line break as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one way:

```
doc, tag, text = Doc().tagtext()

# Do some stuff

# Insert a linebreak in doc
doc._append("<br/>")
```